# Cloudscraper doesn't bypass cloudfare i'm under attack mode

Tags: python, web-scraping, discord.py

i have a project which is scraping a website using the cloudfare devices. It was working since last week. The website is now responding that the browser is outdated and I should update it.
I've installed the last version of cloudscraper and the issue is still the same. When this error doesn't shows up, a second error shows. The website has, Cloudfare i'm under attack mode please wait 5 seconds. I'm using proxies in order to make request. I've changed all of the ips and the issue is still the same. Cloudscraper is supposed to bypass this issue.
How  could I fix all of these  problems?
Thanks for your answer guys and have a nice day.